# cannot run eb push to send new version to elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have just set up a new project, the elastic beanstalk environment is running ok with sample application.  this was all set up with eb cli.

when I try to do eb push with my new application i get the following

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   ".git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push", line 57, in 
>       dev_tools.push_changes(opts.get("env"), opts.get("commit"))   File "/Users/Mark/workspace/edu/gc/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.py", line
>   196, in push_changes
>       self.create_application_version(env, commit, version_label)   File "/Users/Mark/workspace/edu/gc/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.py", line
>   184, in create_application_version
>       self.upload_file(bucket_name, archived_file)   File "/Users/Mark/workspace/edu/gc/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.py", line
>   145, in upload_file
>       key.set_contents_from_filename(archived_file)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto-2.28.0-py2.7.egg/boto/s3/key.py",
>   line 1315, in set_contents_from_filename
>       encrypt_key=encrypt_key)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto-2.28.0-py2.7.egg/boto/s3/key.py",
>   line 1246, in set_contents_from_file
>       chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto-2.28.0-py2.7.egg/boto/s3/key.py",
>   line 725, in send_file
>       chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto-2.28.0-py2.7.egg/boto/s3/key.py",
>   line 914, in _send_file_internal
>       query_args=query_args   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto-2.28.0-py2.7.egg/boto/s3/connection.py",
>   line 633, in make_request
>       retry_handler=retry_handler   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto-2.28.0-py2.7.egg/boto/connection.py",
>   line 1046, in make_request
>       retry_handler=retry_handler)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto-2.28.0-py2.7.egg/boto/connection.py",
>   line 919, in _mexe
>       request.body, request.headers)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto-2.28.0-py2.7.egg/boto/s3/key.py",
>   line 815, in sender
>       http_conn.send(chunk)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py",
>   line 805, in send
>       self.sock.sendall(data)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py",
>   line 229, in sendall
>       v = self.send(data[count:])   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py",
>   line 198, in send
>       v = self._sslobj.write(data) socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe Cannot run aws.push for local repository HEAD:

I have another elastic beanstalk app that is running and when I run eb push in that directory it works fine so I dont think its anything to do with ruby or other dependancies not being installed.  I also made changes and made another commit with a very simple message to make sure that wasnt causing the problem and still no joy

the difference between the app that can be pushed and this one is the aws account.  the user credentials for this elastic beanstalk app that wont push are admin credentials

Comment: Independently from this problem, I would encourage you to use the new eb CLI 3.x available at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-eb.html

Answer (score 0):

this link solved my problem, it was as a result of using two different accounts

http://www.acnenomor.com/207992p1/unable-to-deploy-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-using-git